# Incorrect syntax near '@geoPoint'

Tags: c#

Can you identify where my error is?
When I run this I get an error on the `ExecuteNonQuery`

> Incorrect syntax near '@geoPoint'

```
sqlConnection.Open();

string commandText = "INSERT INTO shapefileTest (state, nrng, twp, lgnt, type, ntwp, meridian, rdir, tdir, rng, stcty, county, shape) VALUES ('" + state + "', '" + nrng + "', '" + twp + "' , " + lgnt + ", '" + type + "', '" + ntwp + "', '" + meridian + "', '" + rdir + "', '" + tdir + "', '" + rng + "', '" + stcty + "', '" + county + "',  @geoPoint";

SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@geoPoint";
param.UdtTypeName = "Geography";
param.Value = sqlGeog;

sqlComm.Parameters.Add(param);

sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Have you heard of [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities. Make all input a parameter (it will also increase performance). Also, use a `using` block with ADO.NET objects (or anything that implements the `IDisposable` interface

Comment: Are you missing a closing bracket from your 'Values' entry

Comment: This isn't production code yet.  I'm figuring out how to insert shape data from C# - I will keep the SQL Injection in mind when I go from test to production code.

Comment: @JeffV why bother making `geoPoint` an `SqlParameter` and not the rest then?

Comment: @JeffV: Regardless of whether this is production code or not, you should use parameterized queries. It makes your code *much* clearer - indeed, it would probably have made the SQL simple enough that you wouldn't have had this problem to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the final parens `)` unless that is a typo

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO shapefileTest (
    state, nrng, twp, lgnt, type, ntwp, meridian, rdir, tdir, rng, stcty, county, shape)     
    VALUES ('" + state + "', '" + nrng + "', '" + twp + "' , " + lgnt + ", '" + type 
    + "', '" + ntwp + "', '" + meridian + "', '" + rdir + "', '" + tdir + "', '" 
    + rng + "', '" + stcty + "', '" + county + "',  @geoPoint)";
                                                             ^
                                                             ^
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Oh geez....  Staring me right in the face...  Thank you...  That worked.  I will mark as answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @JeffV Do take note of the other comments that are correct about SQL injection.